# Primary key y alternative key valores duplicados

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hola muy buenas tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con las siguientes claves primarias y restricciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lanzo una query el campo `"IDDOCUMENT"` veo que se puede repetir,lo que me genera dudas es que en la tabla tengo un Alternativekey que se llema AK_PERSON y conStraint UNIQUE por lo tanto no se porque se repite en algunos casos el `idDocuument`.

Tengo claro que la primary key que es el campo `IdPerson` no se puede repetir pues el clave primaria pero no entiendo porque el `"IdDocument"` si se repite.

Porque puede estar pasando esto?

Comment: AK_PERSON tiene pinta de apuntar a IDPERSON no a IDDOCUMENT

Comment: @JDev si,de echo la AK_PERSON (IDNATIONALITY,IDDOCUMENT),pero porque se me duplica en algunos casos el IdDocument?

Comment: Muy simple, estas indicando que sea unico el par IDNATIONALITY, IDDOCUMENT pero por separado no estas indicando que no sean unicos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La columna `IDDOCUMENT` no tiene ninguna restricción `UNIQUE`, por eso se puede repetir.

Añadele a la tabla una constraint UNIQUE

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (IDDOCUMENT);
```